Given the Equation: $px^2 + qy^2 + ax + by + c = 0$, What Conditions on $p, q, a, b$ and $c$ will Make it an Equation of a Circle?
I was able to prove a simpler version of the question without p and q, and arrived at the only condition that $a^2 + b^2 > 4c$ by completing the square and rearranging the equation into this $(x+\frac{a}{2})^2+(y+\frac{b}{2})^2=\frac{a^2+b^2}{4}-c$. As the radius must be positive, $\frac{a^2+b^2}{4}-c>0$.
I wasn't sure how to adapt this approach to this question. I thought of dividing the whole equation by $pq$, but I couldn't take it further.

For a circle, one must have $p=q$ (otherwise, one would have an ellipse or a hyperbola instead).

Let me restate your question to talk about when a conic section in general exists. Complete the square again as usual:
$$p \left(x^2 + \frac{a}{p} x + \frac{a^2}{4p^2} \right) + q \left(y^2 + \frac{b}{q} y + \frac{b^2}{4q^2} \right) - \left(\frac{a^2}{4p} + \frac{b^2}{4q} - c\right) = 0$$
If $p, q > 0$, the sum of squares is zero at its minimum value. So we would need to subtract something which is zero or greater to make the equation possible, and thus:
$$\frac{a^2}{4p} + \frac{b^2}{4q} - c \ge 0$$
Otherwise if at least one of $p, q$ are negative, I suspect this will always give some conic section. (When $p = q = 0$ you get the equation of a straight line, and if one of $p, q$ is zero you get the equation of a parabola.)

It depends if you allow for a point to be included as a 'circle', as it is a degenerate circle. If not, you would have $>$ instead of $\ge$.

If one of $p$ and $q$ is positive and the other negative, then one has the equation of a hyperbola. If both are negative, then one must have $\frac{a^2}{4p} + \frac{b^2}{4q} - c \le 0$ instead.
